# Tracking changes between files or strings (ckeditor-track-changes)

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem. I am using ckeditor track changes (https://github.com/loopindex/ckeditor-track-changes).

I realized that changes made in real time receives tags, like:

`<span class="ice-del ice-cts-1">...</span>`

I need determine the changes between versions of a text.

There is a way to "update" the content of ckeditor and the changes are marked automatically?